# Maven dependency javax.servlet must be included in POM for new build server

Tags: java, maven, servlets

I have a new nexus server, and a new build server. I mvn package a project and get the  following error when it gets to the testing phase:

```
org.mule.api.registry.RegistrationException: Failed to invoke lifecycle phase "initialise" on object: org.mule.config.bootstrap.SimpleRegistryBootstrap@191a01dd (org.mule.api.lifecycle.LifecycleException)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 80 more
NOT FOUND
```

I created a barebone archetype pom as I was troubleshooting this. This included javax.servlet, so I figured that might be it, and it did seem to solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>${servlet-api-release-version}</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Open ended question - why might this be?

Comment: where is the open end.. you closed all..:)

Answer (score 1):

When you are compiling classes which are importing something from `javax.servlet` package, you need to have that dependency on your class path.

For example when you have `public class FooServlet extends HttpServlet`, then the Java compiler needs to be able to get `javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet` to check whether the parent is not `final`, whether you are implementing all abstract methods, etc.

---

`javax.servlet` dependency then needs to be marked as `provided` in `pom.xml`. This is because all servlet containers already include that dependency. If you fail to exclude this library from you WAR, the `HttpServlet` class in your web application will be different from `HttpServlet` class used by the servlet container (i.e. `FooServlet instanceof HttpServlet` would be false as classes in Java are not only defined by their qualified name, but also by their class loader).